# How do I find all exact matches within a block of text in Elasticsearch?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, exact-match

I've got an index of hundreds of book titles in elasticserch, with documents like:

`{"_id": 123, "title": "The Diamond Age", ...}`

And I've got a block of freeform text entered by a user. The block of text could contain a number of book titles throughout it, with varying capitalization.

I'd like to find all the book titles in the block of text, so I can link to the specific book pages.

Any idea how I can do this? I've been looking around for exact phrase matches in blocks of text, with no luck.

Comment: have you tried match_phrase query? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: @salyh I thought that with `match_phrase`, I provide a phrase, and ES finds documents that contain the phrase. I want to do the opposite. I have a list of "phrases" (book titles). I want to pass in a blob of text, and find all the "phrases" that are in the document. Could I do this with `match_phrase`?

Comment: than use percolator: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html - for es 0.90 its here http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/search-percolate.html#search-percolate

Answer (score 0):

You need to index the field title as not_analyzed or using keyword analyzer.
This will tell elasticsearch to do no operations on the field whenever you send a query and this will make you be able to do an exact match search.

I would suggest that you keep an analyzed version as well as a not_analyzed version in order to be able to do exact searches as well as analyzed searches. Your mappings would go like this, in this case I assume that the type name is movies in your case.

```
"mappings":{
  "movies":{
    "properties":{
      "title":{
        "type": "string",
        "fields":{
          "row":{
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you two fields title which contains an analyzed title and title.row which contains the exact value indexed with absolutely no processing.

title.row would match if you entered an exact